# High transaction SQL Server with Availability Groups - Can it work?

Tags: sql-server, replication, high-availability

We have an application that processes an incoming stream of data (100 items per sec or so). We recently switched to Availability Groups on the same DC. So we have two DB nodes and one witness - synchronous replication. We had to change the recovery mode to full recovery in this process.

After we put this into prod (where the stream has the volume mentioned above) the whole thing grinds to a halt. Loads of timeouts, huge select times. Our indexes are re-built.

Is this a matter of availability groups not being the right choice here? Or is it a matter of the full recovery option?

Thanks

Comment: Troubleshoot it just like anything else: waits and queues. That is, what is waiting and what is it waiting on? But, you made quite a few changes at once (recovery model, availability group, *synchronous* availability group), any one of which could be your bottleneck.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the waits and queues and how I could use those to see what things are waiting on? I suspect its disk IO

Comment: I just threw "waits and queues" into google and the very first link is to a whitepaper for SQL 2005 (still applicable today) on the waits and queues methodology. Go read that.

Comment: I see! Apologies I missed it. Thanks a lot.